# 3045 : The Currency field is missing

Tags: salesforce, opayo

I'm getting following error in salesforce integration with [sagepay test environment](https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp). I'm using 'AES128' Algorithm.

```
This transaction attempt has failed. We are unable to redirect you back to the web store from which you were purchasing. The details of the failure are given below.

Status: MALFORMED

Status Detail:  3045 : The Currency field is missing.
```

My Source System is Salesforce. We are using AES128 Crypto algorithm.

```
Blob stringToEncrypt = Blob.valueOf('VendorTxCode=Vtest&Amount=10&Currency=GBP&Description=test description&SuccessURL=https://ap1.salesforce.com/a01&FailureURL=https://ap1.salesforce.com/a01&BillingSurname=Ravi&BillingFirstnames=test ravi&BillingAddress1=BillAddressLine1&BillingCity=Atlanta&BillingPostCode=30004&BillingCountry=US&DeliverySurname=test&DeliveryFirstnames=Fnames&DeliveryAddress1=test&DeliveryCity=Atlanta&DeliveryPostCode=3004&DeliveryCountry=US');

Blob cryptoKey = Blob.valueOf('key');
Blob encryption = Crypto.encrypt('AES128', cryptoKey, cryptoKey, stringToEncrypt);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the padding is PCKS#5? Error 3045 (currency) is the first to crop up when the encryption is wrong....

Comment: Yes padding is PCKS#5.
my encryption password is also correct one. i triple checked..
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Crypto_Class